# How to create a trigger using Sequel Pro

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a trigger on a db. I can get this to work fine in SQL fiddle, but when I attempt to create the trigger in Sequal Pro I just get an error..

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL 
server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8
```

This is the SQL fiddle..  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e849f/1

The procedure I use is to execute the following command in the query window once I've created the schema..

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_selectoin 
BEFORE UPDATE ON main 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
   IF NEW.state = 3 THEN 
   UPDATE selection s JOIN main m 
      ON m.main_id = s.id
      SET s.allow = 1, last_update_timestamp = NOW()
   WHERE s.id = NEW.main_id; 
 END IF;
END;
```

Comment: guessing: If I press the fiddle I see (as expected) a changed "end-of-command" (sorry, forgot the correct term) character (a `|` in this case?), but I don't see that in your code here? You have a `;` in the middle of that begin/end (logically) so your 'normal' end-of-command should be something else or you'll get confusion?

Comment: Maybe an error is ';' at the end of END clause

Answer (score 6):

For anyone having the same issue:

Sequel Pro creates the surrounding statement by itself.
So the statement should look like this:

```
IF NEW.state = 3 THEN 
  UPDATE selection s JOIN main m 
    ON m.main_id = s.id
    SET s.allow = 1, last_update_timestamp = NOW()
  WHERE s.id = NEW.main_id;
END IF;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting a delimiter:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER upd_selectoin 
BEFORE UPDATE ON main 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
   IF NEW.state = 3 THEN 
   UPDATE selection s JOIN main m 
      ON m.main_id = s.id
      SET s.allow = 1, last_update_timestamp = NOW()
   WHERE s.id = NEW.main_id; 
 END IF;
END;
//
```