# Creating trigger with Sequel Ace for MariaDB

Tags: triggers, mariadb, sequelace

I want to create a trigger that updates two fields in a table, the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblForm` (
  `intPri` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `intEmployed` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `vcFirstName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `vcSurName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `vcAddress` text NOT NULL,
  `vcSex` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `dtWhen` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `tmWhen` time DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`intPri`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

I want the trigger to populate and update *dtWhen* and *tmWhen* when a new record is inserted or updated.  How do I do this using the *Sequel Ace* application ?

The database is *MariaDB 11.1.2 client 15.2 for osx10.17 (x86_64)*. I'm working on *iMAC* running *macOS Monterey version 12.7*, *Sequel Ace 4.0.9 Build 20052*.

Edit, found this:
[How to create a trigger using Sequel Pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251236/how-to-create-a-trigger-using-sequel-pro)